# React router does not rendering anything

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

this is the signin code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme();

export default function SignIn() {
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log({
      email: data.get('email'),
      password: data.get('password'),
    });
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
        <CssBaseline />
        <Box
          sx={{
            marginTop: 8,
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <Avatar sx={{ m: 1, bgcolor: 'secondary.main' }}>
            <LockOutlinedIcon />
          </Avatar>
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
            Sign in
          </Typography>
          <Box component="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
            <TextField
              margin="normal"
              required
              fullWidth
              id="email"
              label="Email Address"
              name="email"
              autoComplete="email"
              autoFocus
            />
            <TextField
              margin="normal"
              required
              fullWidth
              name="password"
              label="Password"
              type="password"
              id="password"
              autoComplete="current-password"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
              label="Remember me"
            />
            <Button
              type="submit"
              fullWidth
              variant="contained"
              sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
            >
              Sign In
            </Button>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs>
                <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                  Forgot password?
                </Link>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                  {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                </Link>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

this the signup code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';



const theme = createTheme();

export default function SignUp() {
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log({
      email: data.get('email'),
      password: data.get('password'),
    });
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
        <CssBaseline />
        <Box
          sx={{
            marginTop: 8,
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <Avatar sx={{ m: 1, bgcolor: 'secondary.main' }}>
            <LockOutlinedIcon />
          </Avatar>
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
            Sign up
          </Typography>
          <Box component="form" noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit} sx={{ mt: 3 }}>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <TextField
                  autoComplete="given-name"
                  name="firstName"
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  id="firstName"
                  label="First Name"
                  autoFocus
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <TextField
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  id="lastName"
                  label="Last Name"
                  name="lastName"
                  autoComplete="family-name"
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  id="email"
                  label="Email Address"
                  name="email"
                  autoComplete="email"
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  name="password"
                  label="Password"
                  type="password"
                  id="password"
                  autoComplete="new-password"
                />
              </Grid>
            
            </Grid>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              fullWidth
              variant="contained"
              sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
            >
              Sign Up
            </Button>
            <Grid container justifyContent="flex-end">
              <Grid item>
                <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                  Already have an account? Sign in
                </Link>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Box>
        </Box>
        
      </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

this the app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SignUp from './containers/SignUp'
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import SignIn from './containers/SignIn';
import Home from "./containers/Home"

export default function App(){
return(
    
    <Router> 
        <div>
        <Route path="/"> <Home/> </Route> 
        <Route path="/signin"> <SignIn/> </Route>
        <Route path="/signup"> <SignUp/> </Route>
        </div>
    </Router>
)

}
```

there is also a home.js i am sure it doesn't have any errors.
index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import SignUp from './containers/SignUp'
import SignIn from './containers/SignIn'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

when I run this code it renders nothing . and also doesnt show any errors. please help me.

I have tried the above code . It shows no error. when I try to render a component without using routes it works perfectly fine.

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` is installed? Check by running `npm list react-router-dom` from the project directory.

Comment: If you use react-router-dom version ^6, add `Routes` component above all `Route`s will probably solve this.

Comment: @Bar717 I suspect OP isn't using v6 since they say there are no errors. V6 `Route` components don't render routed content as children of routes and ***must*** be rendered within the `Routes` component as you point out. But maybe we'll hear back they do in fact have v6 installed and there *are* actually errors.

Comment: Right, it is not V6. It may sound odd but it might be the spaces between the child components of each Route (space counts as a child).

Comment: I am using version 6 . tried wrapping route with routes still it doesnt render anything.and also doesnt show any errors.

Answer (score 0):

The `Route` component API changed significantly in `react-router-dom@6`. The `Route` components are necessarily rendered directly by the `Routes` component and the routed components are rendered *exclusively* in the `element` prop.

Example:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import SignUp from './containers/SignUp';
import SignIn from './containers/SignIn';
import Home from './containers/Home';

export default function App() {
  return(
    <Router> 
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} /> 
        <Route path="/signin" element={<SignIn />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```